# Selecting PHP data by date for the last 7 days from mysql database with a different date layout

Tags: mysql

I have a transactions table in my database where the date is stored in the `date` field like this: `2014-08-30 02:22:35`.

I'm making basic analytics and need to be able to display all transactions for each day for the last 7 days but am a little confused as to how I can achieve this when there is a timestamp along with the date stored in the same field.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You can get the last seven days with:

```
where `date` >= CURDATE() - interval 7 day
```

This will go back seven days, ignoring the time field.

I'm not sure what you mean by "display all transactions for each day for the past 7 days".  You can extract just the `date` for the field using `date` (so, `date(date)`) and use the value for filtering, aggregation, or sorting.